# Can you use the IIS 7.0 Powershell SnapIn with IIS 7 Express

Tags: powershell, iis-express

I'm trying to setup a couple of default bindings in my applicationHosts.config file for IISExpress and was wondering if there was any way to script these with the IIS powershell snap in.

Is this possible with IIS Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible use it with IIS Express. Probably you should use appcmd.exe located in the installation folder of IIS Express. (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)